# Writing HaShem's Hebrew Name

Tags: halacha, tefilla, prayer-book

Can I write any of HaShem's Hebrew names in pencil, in my Siddur? Any of his "Hebrew" names that is, not English.

Comment: Sure thing, the only problem with written names is properly disposing of them see Rambam https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904982/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Six.htm

Comment: @AlBerko actually the Gemara prohibits writing God's name in a Siddur.

Comment: Which Gemara is that? And is it codified Halacha? @DoubleAA